# Socket, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, tkinter, attributes

If anyone actually reads this thanks!
 Anyway on to the problem, every time I run my code I get an 'AttributeError' and I can't find where the issue is. I'm using Socket, tKinter, os and multiprocessing. Here's my code(I know its now the most pythony thing in the world but hey I'm just playing with sockets):

```
#---Import statments---#
import socket, os, multiprocessing
import tkinter as tk

#---global variables---#
setup = ''
cleintsocket = ''

#---Defs---#
def setup():
    global host, port, user
    host = setup_host_box.get()
    port = setup_port_box.get()
    user = setup_user_box.get()

def connect(self, hostname, connectingport):
    self.connect((hostname, int(connectingport)))
    print('connected')
    multiprocessing.Process(target = resv()).start()

def create_sock(nhost, nport):
    global cleintsocket
    cleintsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connect(cleintsocket, nhost, nport)

def send(username, cleintsock):
    '''to send a message'''
    usrmsg = (username + ' - ' + chat_msg_box.get()).encode()
    cleintsock.send(usrmsg)

def resv(sock):
    '''resive subscript, run through mutiprosses module'''
    while True:
        rmsg = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        chat_msg_display_text.insert('end.0.', rmsg)

def chat():
    '''loads chat page'''
    setup_host_text.pack_forget()
    setup_host_box.pack_forget()
    setup_port_text.pack_forget()
    setup_port_box.pack_forget()
    setup_user_text.pack_forget()
    setup_user_box.pack_forget()
    setup_confirm_button.pack_forget()
    chat_msg_desplay_text.pack()
    chat_msg_box.pack()
    chat_msg_send_button.pack()

def start():
    '''starts the setup page'''
    setup_host_text.pack()
    setup_host_box.pack()
    setup_port_text.pack()
    setup_port_box.pack()
    setup_user_text.pack()
    setup_user_box.pack()
    setup_confirm_button.pack()

#---TK Setup---#
#--window setup--#
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Chat')
window.geometry('600x600')
window.configure(background='#ffffff')
#--connection setup page--#
setup_host_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Host')
setup_host_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_port_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Port')
setup_port_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_user_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Username')
setup_user_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_confirm_button = tk.Button(window,text = 'Connect', command = setup())
#--chat page--#
chat_msg_box = tk.Entry(window, bg='#ffffff')
chat_msg_send_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'send', command = send(user, cleintsocket))
chat_msg_display_text = tk.Text(window, width=600, height=500, wrap = 'word')
#--------------#

start()
```

The python console is saying there is an error here `chat_msg_send_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'send', command = send(user, cleintsocket))` that produces an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'` error however I can't see any problems with it.

Please help.

Thanks again!

EDIT: Here's the error(Not needed now but this is for principle)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../tkcleint.py", line 76, in <module>
    chat_msg_send_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'send', command = send(user, cleintsocket))
  File ".../tkcleint.py", line 29, in send
    cleintsock.send(usrmsg)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: For a start you need to use a `lambda` function in the line raising the `AttributeError`, like this: `chat_msg_send_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'send', command = lambda: send(user, cleintsocket))`. If that solves your problem, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off (as @R.Murry has pointed out) you are calling the functions **immediately** and passing their return value as the command which in this case is `None`, so I'd start by fixing that up:

```
setup_confirm_button = tk.Button(window,text = 'Connect', command = setup) #don't call setup here
...
def send_button_callback():
    send(user, cleintsocket)
chat_msg_send_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'send', command = send_button_callback)
```

next, it is important to include the **whole** error message in your question because that is not the line that is running into problems:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 76, in <module>
    chat_msg_send_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'send', command = send(user, cleintsocket))
  File ".../test.py", line 29, in send
    cleintsock.send(usrmsg)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

You pass the variable `cleintsocket` into `send` and try to use the `.send` method of a socket, however it is initialized to an empty string:

```
cleintsocket = ''
```

so if you call `send` before it is changed to a `socket` you will get that error, simply check whether it has been initialized yet:

```
def send(username, cleintsock):
    '''to send a message'''
    if cleintsock: #not an empty string
        usrmsg = (username + ' - ' + chat_msg_box.get()).encode()
        cleintsock.send(usrmsg)
    #else:window.bell() #play a error beep
```

Comment: @Taghg McDonald-Jensen Thanks for the help! It works fine now.

Comment: Thanks to @R. Murray for the help as well